# Solving a recurrence relation with two variables

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-tree, recurrence

I have this function which traverses each node of a left child-right sibling binary tree once and I want to solve the recurrence relation of the function.

First of all I think the relation looks like this:
`T(n) = 1+m[4+T(n-m)] = 1+4m+mT(n-m)`

Where `m` is the number of nodes on a level and `n` the total amount of nodes in the tree.

Is this correct? And how could I solve this recurrence relation with two variables?

```
void maxWidth(Node node, int height, vector<int> &width){
    if(node==nullptr){
        return;
    }
    while(node!=nullptr){
        if(width.size()==height){
            width.push_back(0);
        }
        if(width.size()>height){
            width[height]=width[height]+1;
        }
        if(node->left_child!=nullptr){
            maxWidth(node->left_child,height+1,width);
        }
        node=node->right_sib;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this question belong to https://cs.stackexchange.com/? It is more theoretical than to do with programming.

Comment: wouldn't it be more like `T(n) = c+mT(n/m)`? Since the recursion call handles around (1/m) of the original tree?

Comment: @DuDa I think reasoning that way it would be (n-m/n) cause you start with n/n nodes and at each call you are left with (n-m/n) nodes until you reach 0/n nodes.

Comment: are you estimating for worst, average or bestcase?

Comment: @DuDa worst case

Comment: mmmhhh... I guess I can't help you much here with concrete formula, but the solution should be linear, since you are handling each node exactly once.

Comment: @ Ok thanks, I posted the question on StackExchange too and got an answer there